# How to embed a pdf file in HTML5?

Tags: html, pdf

I am using HTML5 for my website and I want to display pdf files the user uploaded.
I would like to choose which pages to load(for example view pages 3 to 6).

Just to clarify, I am only asking about the way of viewing the files, not uploading them.

There are a lot of questions like this but they are all fron 2009 and a lot has changed since then.
What is the correct way to do it today?

Comment: The method for embedding hasn't changed since 2009.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed

Comment: Of course, what's your point?  It's the only way to do what you're asking.  Otherwise, you'll have to render that document yourself.

Comment: have you read what you linked me? it literally says it is not wise to use <embed>

Comment: Of course I've read it.  Use it or don't, it's up to you.  It's a well-supported method.  For how much longer... who knows.

Comment: that is why I posted the question, I was looking for a way that doesn't have a warning sign strapped to it's forehead

Comment: If you actually need to embed a real PDF, the only way to do this is with what I linked to.  If you *don't* actually *need* a *real PDF* embedded, then you can render out these pages and display them differently.  Either as raster images, or you can try to get it as SVG.  Your question doesn't have enough detail to know what you actually *need*, which is why I didn't post an answer.  We also have no idea what you've looked at and haven't looked at, because you didn't tell us.

Comment: Yes, a lot has changed since 2009. I think you are looking for PDF.js. https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ If PDF.js is not what you are looking for, please elaborate on why exactly it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?